# Can't see logs of x264 lib

Tags: c++, visual-studio, logging, x264

I have a C++ solution which uses x264.lib. I've set `params.i_log_level = X264_LOG_DEBUG;` in order to be able to see some logging from x264 lib. However during debugging in Visual Studio Output window I do not see any x264 related logs.

How can I see those logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabling log level, you leave default logging handler to generate debug output. This writes to `stderr` and the output does not appear on Visual Studio output window.

```
static void x264_log_default( void *p_unused, int i_level, const char *psz_fmt, 
  va_list arg )
{
    // ...
    fprintf( stderr, "x264 [%s]: ", psz_prefix );
    vfprintf( stderr, psz_fmt, arg );
```

You need to provide your own log function in `params.pf_log` and have the data passed to [`OutputDebugString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API. This way it is going to come up on VS output window.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got the idea. I implemented my own function:
X264_log( void *p_unused, int i_level, const char *psz_fmt, va_list arg)
This function is being called successfully however parameter arg contains some strange symbols instead of normal chars. As a result when passing "arg" to OutputDebugString, in VS Output window I see "???????" or other strange symbols.

Comment: You're doing wrong something, supposedly you are processing Unicode strings wrong. You can have a look at x264's `x264_log_default` implementation to see what it does exactly. Or, you might want to call `OutputDebugStringA` to access ANSI argument string.

Comment: I used OutputDebugStringA. Here is my simple function, where regardless of log level I want to show the log in Output window.
static void X264_log( void *p_unused, int i_level, const char *psz_fmt, va_list arg)
{
    OutputDebugStringA(arg);
};
But here is what I see in Output "¨ë½8q?>`pë½ ßõˆâ½\â½q?"
When during debugging I watch "arg" char array content I see a log of negative numbers which is not normal I think.

Comment: This is incorrect. You need to check what `x264_log_default` does to obtain a string from format + args.

Comment: Whatever I tried I couldn't succeed in using OutputDebugString. However as you suggested I used x264_log_default implementation and instead of stderr I directed to log to some local file. And now I am able to see x264 logs in my file. This is enough for me. Thanks a log for you help.